# Proof that in any base $b$, the result of multipling two numbers of $k$ digits, doesn't recuire more than $2k$ digits

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

The proof that I came up whit is:

Let, $c$ be $b^0 r_0+ b^1 r_1+b^2 r_2+...+b^k r_k$ and $d = b^0 r_0'+ b^1 r_1'+b^2 r_2'+...+b^k r_k'$

then multipling both:

$$(b^0 r_0+ b^1 r_1+b^2 r_2+...+b^k r_k).(b^0 r_0'+ b^1 r_1'+b^2 r_2'+...+b^k r_k')=$$
$$=b^0(r_0r_0')+b'(r_0r_1'+r_1r_0')+...+b^{2k}(r_kr_k')$$

then if $r_kr_k'$ is less than $b$, the proof holds... but if is greater, I don't know what to do.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the largest number with $k$ digits is $b^k-1$ - your examples have $k+1$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

The largest $k$-digit number in base $b$ is $b^k - 1$, squaring this gives $b^{2 k} - 2 b^k + 1 < b^{2 k} - 1$.